# Google Chrome scrolling suddenly stopped on my website

Tags: apache-httpd, chrome, scrolling, php7

I have a website that was working OK until this weekend. Today I noticed that a number of browsers lost the ability to scroll the content vertically. The only modifications done to the server or the code last week were the recommended update/upgrades.
My website uses PHP 7.3 + MariaDb 10.4 + some small JS scripts (jquery-3.4.1.min.js). It is located on a (virtual) Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Apache2 webserver (HTTPS) with 5 GB memory.

I have tested the website on a number of browsers; Firefox on Ubuntu/Deb10 is always OK, Chromium on Debian is also OK.

Chromium on Ubuntu, Vivaldi and Google Chrome on Ubuntu/Deb10 have scrolling problems (all these browsers are the current, stable version).

Win10 with Google Chrome or Edge gave the same problem.

Finally, I opened my website in a working browser, downloaded and copied the page source to a text (.html) file. Opening this file in any or all of the mentioned browsers was OK, scrolling worked perfectly.
Testing with an old version of Google Chrome (chrome64_68.0.3440.84) was also OK, no problems.

I am at a total loss on where to start looking for the root of this behavior, is it my web-server or is it a Chrome problem? If more details are needed, please ask and I will try to add these to my question.

Comment: An URL perhaps? Or do you want us to guess?

Comment: The site contains a fair amount of research stuff, which makes me hesitant to make the URL public. I might be able to create a scaled-down, public, version but an "educated guess" would be OK right now.

Comment: I see the guesses are streaming in.  Doing the scaled down thing is a good idea, you may very well find out what's wrong  yourself.  I would go the other way: start from scratch, adding more and more until you have the problem agein.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I'll try this as soon as possible. I also think that I probably should restrict the tests to Ubuntu (18/20) and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Culprit found. The problem originated in an old, forgotten .css file with a number of statements labeled as "IE hacks", e.g: `table { font-size: 100%;  IE hack  }`

Cleaning this file restored all functionality to Google Chrome and other, related, browsers.

What I cannot answer is why this issue surfaced now, from one day to another, without any error messages or recent code or browser updates. However, that is an entirely different question, and one which I am not going to ask here and now.